# Minecraft Empty Chests Command Block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am using the following Command to spawn a new chest at the given coordinates with stuff in it at each new round:

```
/setblock 264 4 997 minecraft:chest 0 replace {Items:[{id:274,Count:1,Slot:0},{id:275,Count:1,Slot:1}]}
```

The problem with that is that when replacing the old chest all the stuff in the old chest is thrown out. And that's pretty much **not** what I want. I need to find a way to replace a chest which *might* have stuff in it without throwing those things out.

Someone else said I should replace the given position for one tick with lava, which I tried. Works in 90% of the tries (in the other 10% the items from the chest are thrown to far away - out of the spawned lava block), but the problem with that is that I can't use it in wooden areas because it might burn everything down.

Comment: Not exactly sure, but I think you want to use `destroy` instead of `replace`

Comment: @MBraedley I just tested it, `destroy`ing a chest has the same effect.

Comment: This is very strange. Even a temporary `/gamerule doTileDrops false` doesn't work.

Comment: I have this nagging feeling that SethBling figured it out, and I thought it was with `destroy`.

Comment: Yep, its very strange. I THINK destroy is meant to do what i described in my question and replace SHOULD do what i asked for in this question. I guess it's a bug?

Comment: I don't know, I mean, it's doing exactly what is described; it's replacing the chest and not dropping the chest itself. You could figure something out with hoppers and droppers to empty the chests before refilling them, but that only really works for a small set of chests containing a small set of items, and becomes impractical when you include, say, arrows.

Comment: Already tried that. Won't help, because i need to RESET all chests at each round start. By emptying all chests before roundstart with hoppers i just transfer those items to the hopper which leaves me behind with the problem of getting rid of those hoppers. REPLACE on the hoppers, leaves me with the same problem which means that using hoppers i only move the problem by 1 block ;)

Comment: ...so the problem is that the items drop on the ground and are not destroyed? I think the wording is a little vague, by "thrown out" I initially thought you were saying the contents were lost and you didn't want them to be.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the items drop onto the ground which is not what i want - sorry im not a native speaker.

Comment: [Yup, this is a bug.](https://mojang.atlassian.net/browse/MC-11866) Great.

Comment: Guess the only answer is to wait until the next update

Answer (score 3):

As of the latest, latest snapshot (14w02b), this is most certainly possible. In fact, there's an easier way to do the whole thing now, which is awesome. With the `/blockdata` command added in the snapshot, you can modify and overwrite the contents of a tile entity (including a chest), and much, much more. The applications of `/blockdata` go beyond what I can fully comprehend at this point in time, but, for this specific case, it's not too hard.

Let's say for example your equipment chest is supposed to contain a notch apple, a gold sword, a bow, and a stack of arrows. The command for that would be `/blockdata X Y Z {Items:[{id:322,Damage:1,Count:1,Slot:0},{id:283,Count:1,Slot:1},{id:261,Count:1,Slot:2},{id:262,Count:64,Slot:3}]}`, replacing X Y and Z as appropriate. There's a lot of stuff going on in that command, but essentially, you are changing the data of the chest to contain the specified items. It's the same concept as using `/setblock` to spawn a new chest with these items, except instead of replacing the chest, you're overwriting its data.

In this more specific case, you want `/blockdata 264 4 997 {Items:[{id:274,Count:1,Slot:0},{id:275,Count:1,Slot:1}]}`.

And, of course, if you want an *empty* chest, all you need to do is use `/blockdata X Y Z {Items:[]}`

Comment: But this would also overwrite any items still in the chest no?  If you use this command when there is already something in slot 0 for example, would the item in slot 0 not be replaced by your new item?  OP wants it to not be replaced.

Comment: @hammythepig I'm looking at what the OP wants to *do*. What they want to do is reset a bunch of chests at the end of a game. Before, this was possible, but made a mess of items everywhere. This method can be used to clear items (`/blockdata X Y Z {Items:[]}`) to make way for the old method, or, it can replace the old method entirely, and accomplish the whole task in one go. The confusion might come from "not throwing those things out"; that means that he wants a way of replacing chests without having the old contents dropping on the floor.

Comment: Ah correct, I read OP wrong. I thought he wanted to keep the stuff in the chest but he merely didn't want them on the ground.  my bad! :)

Comment: How could I add special data an item say, refilling the chest with __white dyed invulnerable__ leather armor?

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms Yes you can. Use `/blockdata X Y Z {Items:[{id:leather_chestplate,Count:1,Slot,0,tag:{custom tags go here}]}` Preferably start a new thread for that question.

Answer (score 1):

You could have two chests set up and connected with a hopper from one to the other. Use the blockdata tag on the top chest to add the item. It will be sucked into the second chest, and added to whatever items are already there.