# Minecraft spawning items with inventories in them

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was wondering, is there a way to spawn a dispenser that is filled with snowballs using a command? Like, i want to be able to /fill over a row of dispensers with full dispensers... so how would I specify the inventory of the spawned block in the command?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minecraft Empty Chests Command Block](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/142415/minecraft-empty-chests-command-block) (procedurally casting close vote per the answer that quotes an answer to another question)

Answer (score 1):

Please see

[Minecraft Empty Chests Command Block](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/142415/minecraft-empty-chests-command-block)

as I think this answers you question.

> Let's say for example your equipment chest is supposed to contain a notch apple, a gold sword, a bow, and a stack of arrows. The command for that would be /blockdata X Y Z {Items:[{id:322,Damage:1,Count:1,Slot:0},{id:283,Count:1,Slot:1},{id:261,Count:1,Slot:2},{id:262,Count:64,Slot:3}]}, replacing X Y and Z as appropriate. There's a lot of stuff going on in that command, but essentially, you are changing the data of the chest to contain the specified items. It's the same concept as using /setblock to spawn a new chest with these items, except instead of replacing the chest, you're overwriting its data.

Comment: isn't the id a string now in 1.8 not a number?

Answer (score 0):

If you're making something not automatic,fill a dispenser with snowballs(anything with any inventory type will work),and ctrl+select it, eg. ctrl+scrollwheel button.
You're gonna get an item with an NBT tag on it.
Then when you place the item/block down,it will be filled with exact stuff it was filled when you selected it.